# Аргументы функции php

Tags: php, ооп

Можно ли передавать в качестве аргумента функции ссылку на объект? например:

```
$a = new Smarty();
foo($a); // передаем ссылку на объект чтобы использовать его методы внутри функции 
//и в последствии передать эту ссылку другой функции.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, правильно, так можно делать.

```
class A {
    public function test(B $b) {
        $b->testMethod();
    }
}

class B {
    public function testMethod() {
        echo 'I\'m from class B<br/>';
    }
}

function testFunction(B $b) {
    $b->testMethod();
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

$a->test($b);
testFunction($b);
```

оба выведут `I'm from class B`

Comment: А как вы представляете себе передачу **объекта** не по ссылке?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а я написал что можно не по ссылке?

Comment: "_Так что если хотите — делайте._" - как бы намекает, что есть другой путь ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, это намекает на то, что если человек хочет передавать объект как аргумент - пускай передает. Мне не хватало символов для отправки ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы. вопрос возник в результате непонятных ошибок в коде, как бы намекающих что я передаю объект, а передается строка в итоге. Переписал, протестировал, вроде все нормально.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev просто, как я понял, вопрос ТС возник потому, что он всегда сталкивался с передачей в качестве аргументов только строк  и чисел, вот он и спрашивает вообще можно ли объекты впендюрить ли...... .....что примечательно, это опять один из тех вопросов, ответ на который можно проверить самостоятельно

Comment: @Дмитрий тогда нужно было бы другой вопрос задавать с возникшим проблемным местом и кодом. возможно там где-то что-то не так....но это только теперь другим вопросом если)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , не до конца понял в чем проблема была, потому что в итоге переписал все то же самое и сейчас все хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP объекты [передаются по ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.references.php). Так что "*передавать в качестве аргумента функции ссылку на объект*" - не только правильный, но и **единственный путь**.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам понадобится передать статический класс, имеющий определенный интерфейс то делается это так

```
class database implements \Idatabase
{

}

class A
{
 public function __construct($database);
   if(!is_subclass_of($database, \Idatabase::class)){
     return new \Exception('wrong data');
   }
 }
}

new A(database::class);
```